# ntext is incompatible with int MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I was working on sql when I got error: I don't know how to fix it:

`ntext is incompatible with int`

my query is like this

`select * from table1 where id=textfield union select name,age,(here is an ntext value) from table2`

I tried using `convert(myfield as nvarchar(max))` but still no luck and error changed to this:

`The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.`

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: ys sure i want to display two tables data bt unable to do so.. may b i should change the design..

Comment: If you use the correct syntax for converting you datatype I am sure you will have some luck, it is `CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), Myfield)` or `CAST(myfield as nvarchar(4000))`, I think it should work, Also dont do `SELECT *`, use column names in your select statement, just to make sure the order of columns in 1st select matches the order of columns in second select

Comment: @m.ali is probably right, at least include the table definition, is ID an int? the convert textfield to int: convert(int, textfield) or if that's not possible take the substring of textfield: convert(int, substring(textfield, 1, 12))

Comment: thanx to all of you.. yesterday i went through many articles and finally found the solution by using union all clause.. it bypass the data type comparison constraint..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First :

`ntext` is deprecated and should be replaced with `nvarchar(MAX)`.

That aside, `ntext` is not comparable and can't be used with `DISTINCT` or `=`.

When you use the key word `UNION` to join 2 queries it will automatically call a `DISTINCT` operation to join only unique data from both queries.

However, `nvarchar(MAX)` can be used within a `DISTINCT` thus, the best solution is to update your model to use this type instead of `ntext`.

If this can't be done, instead of doing `select * from table1` go with :

```
select field1, field2, Cast(field3 as NVarchar(Max)) 
from table1 
union 
select field1, field2, Cast(field3 as nvarchar(MAX))
from table2
```

Last note :

It is recommended to call your fields explicitly when using a union instead of the `*` wildcard.

Comment: bro i tried bt this didnot worked but i finally found its answer using union all clause

Comment: From the code you posted you only converted the ntext field from the second table whereas you should convert ALL ntext fields.

Union all works since it's not using a distinct clause and therefore might include duplicate rows from table1 and table2.